# Uploading Wordpress site

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, cpanel

So, I have created a wordpress site with database and everything. I used the plugin "duplicator" to store a backup. I now have a folder with all the wordpress php-files and a sql-file as well. Im using localhost.

Now Im trying to upload it to a webhost but Im having some problems to make it work.

Right now Im using Cpanel but I don't understand how to import the wordpress files.
What I have done so far is installing Wordpress with softaculous, checked, tried to upload sql-file in phpmyadmin, not checked, and tried to upload all the wordpress files to public_html, not checked as well.

Does it exist any easier way to upload all files to a webhost or could anyone guide me through the progess. I would be grateful!

If I have forgotten to mention anything please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: adding a little on the comment from @UglyEddie, you could use cpanel to create a ftp account, use that account in combination with filezilla (client application) to upload the files to your public_html , then go to mysql to create a user and a database for your website, go to phpmyadmin in cpanel and import the sql file. The last step is to change the wordpress config so that it uses your newly created database and to test everything out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the steps:

1. Upload all the wordpress files and folder on you hosting using cPanel
2. Import the database using the PhpMyAdmin.
3. Make the necessary changes in the wp-config i.e the DB_NAME(Database name), 
   DB_USER(Name of the user whom the database privileges are assigned to), DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST
4. Then later execute the following query, note: wp_ is prefix of table. If you have changed the prefix of the table at the time of installation then use that prefix with wp_ in the below query

   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'old_domain_url_here', 'new_domain_url_here') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'old_domain_url_here', 'new_domain_url_here');

   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'old_domain_url_here', 'new_domain_url_here');

For more details please visit the below link:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a few really good tutorials on the web. Have a look at this link:
http://www.jasonbobich.com/web-design/moving-wordpress-to-a-new-server/#comment-2117

Use FileZilla to upload the actual content: https://filezilla-project.org
You will need your Host, ex example.com, Username and password details provided by your web host to upload your site.

The above tutorial explains everything step by step, very useful.

Comment: Do I upload the whole "backup" with sql file along, or do I just upload zip format? What do you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest not uploading a zip file, upload all the files that are in your localhost (the actual files not zipped). Also, use PHP MyAdmin to import your sql file into your new database. So you wouldn't need to upload the sql file along with your site content.

Comment: So I have connected to the FTP and accessed the files. Which directory should I upload these? public_html?

Comment: Yes you should upload it to public_html